# This code generates five columns with 6 childs but according to this code it should generate six columns. What is the problem?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code which should generate 6 columns but instead generating 5.
Please point out any logical error in the code due to which desired output cannot be obtained.

```
sem1Data= new String[18];
    sem2Data= new String[18];

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int stdA = 0, stdB = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            int colCounter = 1;

            LabName = editText.getText().toString();
            setLabRef = database.getReference("/" + LabName);
            String colName;


            for (int i = 0; i <6; i++) {
                colName = "col" + colCounter;
                //Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, colCounter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if ( colCounter%2 == 0) {

                    for ( ; stdB<18; stdB++)
                    {

                        if(counter<6)
                        {
                            setLabRef.child(colName).child(String.valueOf(counter)).setValue(sem2Data[stdB]);
                            counter++;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            counter=0;
                            colCounter++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    for ( ; stdA<18; stdA++)
                    {
                        if (counter<6){

                            setLabRef.child(colName).child(String.valueOf(counter)).setValue(sem1Data[stdA]);
                            counter++;
                        }
                        else {
                            counter=0;
                            colCounter++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The expected result should be 6 generated columns in firebase but instead only five are generated.

[firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sr67.png)

Answer (score 0):

In first loop change validation block to i <=6 or i < 7

for( int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)

UPD:
if(counter<7)

Comment: by updating counter to six, one child value increased in every column but number of columns are still 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the purpose of your code but here is my opinion , it might help you to clear things out.

if you will add the line `Log.d(TAG, "Log track : stdB : " + stdB  +" stdA : " +stdA);` At the beginning of your for-loop , you will see that the values of `stdA` and `stdB` never set to zero in they just keep increasing according to the logic of your code , actually the both end with the values :

`Log track : stdB : 12 stdA : 18`

now , if you will look at the case where `colCounter = 5 , i = 4` the value of `stdA is 12`
.
Thats mean that the for-loop at the `else` section will run (`colCounter mod 2 is not zero`) **only 6 times** and by that will not execute:

```
  else
      {
       counter=0;
       colCounter++;
         break;
        }
```

and by that you are missing the increase of `colCounter` from `5` to `6` .

Comment: anyway to execute the else part one more time to increase counter from 5 to 6

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve , but you can init  stdA and stdB in the for loop like : `for(stdA = 0 ; stdA < 18 ; stdA++)` and same for stdB